# Classification on the basis of shape and size

Tags: python, opencv, classification

How to classify objects on the basis of shape and size using machine learning?
Say I've an circle and some small dotted squares in an image. The difference between the two is their shape and size. So given an image, how to distinguish between these objects and return the result.
In the actual problem those objects are hot spots in a solar PV folder, which are defected parts of it. I need to classify them.The I/P image is as:

[This is less or more a square type of hot spot:]

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JL7E.png

Comment: I see two possible ways: 1) use as input the image and use convolutional neural nets as classifier 2) find a way to represent the image e.g. Pixel intensity and use these values as features for a classifier (LDA,SVM)

Comment: Histogram of oriented Gradients (HoG) combined with SVM is a classifier based on shape.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer doesn't ellaborate machine learning or any approach using classifiers*

> The circles can be detected by the [Hough Circle
>   Transform](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html#hough-circles)
>   from OpenCV `cv2.HoughCircles()`:

[Documentation for Hough Circles in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles)

*Note*: By using the radius you can tune the shape size of the circles you want to detect. And to be honest I didn't really get what dotted squares are, maybe you could show an exemplary image in your question.

If there are only two different kinds of objects in the image you probably don't even need a classifier, because the two classes are already being separated by the subsequent image processing (that though depends highly on your input images).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result of the code is as follows

[image: Result of the code]

Comment: Okay it doesn't follow a machine learning approach (which I note at the beginning of my answer). Still it can be used to distinguish between two different objects and return the result, which is stated in the question: "So given an image, how to distinguish between these objects and return the result."

Comment: Fair enough. I think it would be better to clarify in comments on the OP before assuming this is the answer they want, though.

Comment: I think it didn't hurt me or anyone else to assume the intent of the OP, maybe it is even helpful to him or to the discussion to clarify the actual question. If I am completely off I am happy to delete my answer once the question is fully understood and answered.

Comment: Well thank-you very much sirs. The information provided is indeed very much helpful. I've edited my question a little bit.Please go through it once more. Here the need of using ML and classification is because of some predictive analysis. Any suggestions or clarifications regarding the question are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sir, I can have different kind of shapes like rectangle or square or circular i.e. shape is the difference here. Plus I also need to distinguish my shapes on the basis of size like small rectangles or big etc. Hope this clarifies. @musked